# VS2013 high CPU usage at break point during debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have been suffering for quite a while with extremely high cpu usage of the devenv.exe executable during debugging. Everything crawls to a halt, it often takes minutes for anything to happen, window often show Not Responding up top, spinning wheel of death. Often get Visual Studio is Busy popup etc.

Debugging MVC .NET web application. Source is on TFS 2010 server. This is the Ultimate VS2013 edition. I don't seem to recall it was an issue until maybe 3 weeks ago, but my sense of time is known be off...

I tried taking a trace, nothing really showed up, except it seemed spending a lot of time starting new threads, no indication which since I don't have the VS pdf files. Anybody got ideas what I can do to figure out what it is doing (or not), to get a clue what to potentially turn off?

Did the following:

- Upgraded to version 5.
- Running in /SafeMode
- Turned off Browser Link
- Checked Enable Just My Code
- Unchecked Require source files to exactly match the original version

Everything compiles really fast and no problem getting debugging started. Outside of the debugging in edit mode things are fast and slick. Also running in debug mode is fairly fast. The brick wall is hit when a breakpoint is reached and then everything goes haywire.

Anybody know anything to try?

[image: Debug Settings]

Comment: Does it happen when you debug any other applications?

Comment: Just tried debugging a regular service app, doesn't seem to have the same issue.

Comment: I don't have the solution, I just have exactly the same problem and can't figure out why. Debugging works one day and doesn't the next without code changes. Fun.

Comment: Not sure if this is the real culprit or not, but I decided for "fun" to turn off intellitrace, and at least the last 3 debug sessions has been blissful, absolutely no cpu utilization showing up, all interaction is prompt and not like walking in quick-sand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off intellitrace seemed to have fixed the problem for me. Not sure why intellitrace think it needs to run when a break point is hit, since everything is supposed to come to a screeching halt, seems like a bug to me.